# Cannot edit code in netbeans when managing merge conflict in a file

Tags: git, netbeans, merge, edit, conflict

I'm working with Git and Netbeans. Both tools are awesome. I just have a small problem when trying to resolve merge conflict among a file:
I cannot edit the code. I can only choose among the codes that are displayed in the merge conflicts resolver. But I would like to have more possibilities:
- keep the changes from both file
- adding changes to a file
However, as I'm not allow to edit files in Netbeans, I cannot do this stuff. I think it's possible if I edit the file as a txt document with Notepad++. However I would rather stay in the Netbeans environnement.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible :( The relevant bug is here: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=141198 You should go vote on it, so hopefully it gets added sooner, because this is a pain point in NB.

Comment: Netbean's bugzilla shows the bug was fixed on September. I am using latest 7.4 but there is still no possibility to merge changes line by line joining both sides. Do you know maybe how to get it working?

Comment: I do not. I'm not sure what the status of this is at this point. It may be worth checking in the 8.0 beta to see if the feature is working there.